# linq query to return 1 row with complex values instead of 2

Tags: linq, automapper

```
var query = from t1 in Context.Table1
    join t2 in Context.Table2 on t1.Id equals t2.Id
    join t3 in Context.Table3 on t3.Id equals t1.Id
    join t4 in Context.Table4 on t1.Id equals t4.Id into temp
    from temp_values in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where t1.Id == id
    select new
    {
        Field1 = t1.Id,
        Field2 = t1.Field2,
        SpecialField = t4.temp_values
    };
```

I have this Linq query that returns 2 rows, because of the last join with Table4.

Notice that both rows have the same values on Field1 and Field2.

Any smart way to return instead just 1 row, that has SpecialField marked as a List that has all the temp_values stores in it?

so instead of:

```
Field1 / Field2/ SpecialField
1           /2          /{ Id=1, Prop1=2, Prop1=3}
1           /2          /{ Id=2, Prop1=12, Prop1=13}
```

I want:

```
Field1 / Field2/ SpecialField
1           /2          /List with 2 entries: { Id=1, Prop1=2, Prop1=3}, { Id=2, Prop1=12, Prop1=13}
```

Comment: groupby is always an option but first we should check why it not working properly in first place

Comment: Amir , it works (no errors) just not as intended.